# How to git merge with only file-level diffs for text files?

Tags: git, github

We have a git repository (on GitHub) with a directory of special text files.  When merging a branch, conflict detection must always happen at the file-level rather than the line-level.  In other words, conflicted files should never be combined and one file should always replace the other-- essentially, merging with the same strategy applied to binary files.

Files will never be renamed or moved.

What's the best solution for this situation?

**Update**:
I tried to pose the question more generically, but what we want in practice is:

When merging from the upstream repo:

- If a file is modified in the upstream repo AND downstream file is unmodified, choose the upstream version.
- If downstream file has modifications, choose downstream version.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually what you want: "conflicted files should never be combined and one file should always replace the other". It sounds like you might want this regardless if the file has conflicts?

Comment: @TTT  I posed the question more generically, but what we want in practice is:  When merging from the upstream repo, if a file is modified in the upstream repo AND downstream file is unmodified, choose the upstream version.  If downstream file has modifications, choose downstream version.

Comment: Right- that's what I figured you meant. But that's not going to make the file be a "conflict" unless lines close together were modified in both places. I was simply questioning your usage of the word "conflict" in this case. Regardless, I believe [knittl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74075266/184546) gets you very close to what you want. (It forces the conflict regardless of whether it normally would have conflicts, and then you take the side you want.)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a [`.gitattributes` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and mark those files as binary/unmergable:

```
path/to/your/dir/* binary
```

If you only want to prevent merging, but still allow diffs:

```
path/to/your/dir/* -merge
```